# How to realize this method only with Streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

```
    /**
     * Get all cities near current city in radius.
     *
     * @param cityName - city
     * @param radius   - radius in kilometers for search
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if city with cityName city doesn't exist.
     */
    public List<String> getCitiesNear(String cityName, int radius) {

        List<String> nearCities = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Integer> distances = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.citiesNames().size(); i++) {
            distances.add(this.getDistance(cityName, this.citiesNames().get(i)));

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < distances.size(); i++) {
            if (distances.get(i) <= radius) {
                if (!this.citiesNames().get(i).equals(cityName)) {
                    nearCities.add(this.citiesNames().get(i));
                }
            }
        }

        return nearCities;
    }
```

Method citiesNames() returns List<"String">. The names of cities.

Method "int getDistance(String srcCityName, String destCityName)" returns distance between srcCityName and srcCityName.

PS:
It is forbidden to use loops, iterators inside this class. Only streams and methods that accept predicates can be used. You cannot declare other fields in the class.

This is my homework)

Comment: you can finish this homework by using map and filter from stream api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
if (citiesNames().contains(cityName) {
    return citiesNames().stream()
                        .filter(city -> getDistance(cityName, city) <= radius)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(cityName + " not found.");
}
```

`filter` method returns a stream that contains only the near cities.
`collect` method creates a `List` containing all the elements in the filtered stream.

Comment: Amazing! Very laconic solution due to Stream and Lambda. It seems that filter() method compares each element of List<String> (etc citiesNames()) with condition into filter(). And then, only filtered elements will be added to the new List<String>

Answer (score 1):

What about using separate classes to store `cityName` and `distance`?
This will get you **ordered** list of all cities that are closer than `radius` to the target city.

```java
private final Set<String> cityNames = Set.of();

public List<String> getCitiesNear(String cityName, int radius) {
    class CityDistance {

        final String cityName;
        final int distance;

        public CityDistance(String cityName, int distance) {
            this.cityName = cityName;
            this.distance = distance;
        }

    }

    return cityNames.stream()
                    .map(curCityName -> new CityDistance(cityName, getDistance(cityName, curCityName)))
                    .filter(cityDistance -> cityDistance.distance <= radius)
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(one -> one.distance))
                    .map(cityDistance -> cityDistance.cityName)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private int getDistance(String cityNameOne, String cityNameTwo) {
    return 0;
}
```